# Office Automation with #import harmful?

Tags: visual-c++, com, import, office-automation

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CppAutomateOutlook-55251528 states:

> [...] It is very powerful, but often not recommended because of
>   reference-counting problems that typically occur when used with the
>   Microsoft Office applications. [...]

Which reference-counting problems are specifically meant here?
For example, does it apply to the particular example?

Similarly as in the example, I just want to open Outlook, create an appointment, done.

I wanted to use #import but this statements makes me feel afraid about it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [circular reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) happens when you have two or more objects holding references to each other, directly or indirectly. In COM, it means that circularly linked objects have called `IUnknown::AddRef` on each other.

In case with Excel automation, that could happen if you connect your event handler (sink) to Excell objects sourcing events (via `IConnectionPoint::Advise`). This way, you may be keeping a reference to e.g., `Application` object, while `Application` object keeps a reference to your sink.

This problem is not specific to smart pointers generated by VC++ `#import` directive. It's about how you handle the shutdown of the COM objects when you no longer need them. You should explicitly break all connections you've made (i.e., do `IConnectionPoint::Unadvise`), and call any explicit shutdown API the object may expose (e.g., `Workbook::Close` or `Application::Quit`). Then you should explicitly release you reference (e.g, call `workbookPtr.Release()` on a smart pointer).

That said, if you don't handle any COM events sourced by Excel, you shouldn't be worrying much, the chance you might create a circular reference would be low. Besides, Excel is an out-of-process COM server, and COM has some [garbage collection logic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171414) in place to manage life-time of out-of-process servers. However, while your application is still open, the Excel process will be kept alive until all references to its object have been released, or `Application::Quit` has been called.

Comment: Great, thanks! I know about circular references but I did not know that this was the reason for this statement. So I can safely use #import with this in mind.

Comment: @divB, execute "the normal level of precaution" unless you handle events. Otherwise, execute "the high level of precaution" and explicitly release any smart pointers when you're done with a particular Excel object. **If your app terminates, but Excel.exe still hangs in the process list for longer than a few seconds, that would be a bad sign.**

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty nonsensical.  Programming Office interop with the aid of #import is the boilerplate and recommended way.  The smart pointer types it auto-generates are explicitly intended to get reference counting done automatically for you so you can't forget to call Release().  There are a few sharp edges, you do have to understand what smart pointers can do and not do.

This is otherwise par for the course for the team that's behind the All-In-One Code Framework.  The samples are created by a support team in Shanghai, originally hired to help out in the MSDN forums.  These guys don't have the kind of credentials you'd expect from a Microsoft programmer that works in Redmond and their snippets are not being reviewed.  Some of them are outright ill conceived.  If you ever asked questions at the MSDN forums and saw the answers they post then you know what I mean.

Their Solution2.cpp sample uses late-binding through IDispatch.  That's definitely the hard way to interop with Office, you get no help whatsoever when you write the code.  IntelliSense is unable to give you any useful information when you write the method call nor can the compiler tell you that you missed an argument or got the argument type wrong.  Your program will fail at runtime with an opaque error code, like DISP_E_BADVARTYPE or DISP_E_BADPARAMCOUNT.  And the Release() calls have to be made explicitly, that of course makes it *easier* to miss one.  Problems you don't have when you use the smart pointers, they give you auto-completion and type checking.  You can see for yourself how much smaller and readable Solution1.cpp is.

Diagnosing a missed call to Release() is otherwise easy, your program completes but you'll still see Outlook.exe running in Task Manager.  Something you'll get used to checking anyway, it will also happen when you debug your program, find a bug and stop the program to make a correction.  Which of course also prevents Release() from being called so Outlook will keep running.  You have to kill it yourself.

Do consider writing this kind of code in a managed language like C# or VB.NET.  You'll get a *lot* more help if you have a problem and you'll find lots of sample code.  And the garbage collector *never* forgets to make a Release call.  It is just a bit slow at doing so.